# Arduino and Display in different rooms, possible?

Tags: lcd, spi, distance

I only wondering which four pins I have to connect for the [LCD4884 from SainSmart](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-graphic-lcd4884-shield-for-arduino-duemilanove-uno-mega2560-mega1280.html), because I want to have Arduino and the LCD in different rooms. Is it possible?

Comment: Regarding wire length, "different rooms" could cover quite a range, e.g. <1m to >10m. Can you give your best estimate of the distances involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your question doesn't really have anything to do with the arduino and the display being in different rooms. The part you linked to has an SPI interface so you will need to use the SCK, MOSI, MISO and a CS line. See [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) for an explanation of using the Arduino's SPI hardware.

As for having the two in separate rooms, the naive approach is to just make the wires for the above described connections really long. This may or may not work depending on several things including clock speed, line impedance, environmental interference, etc. I am not an expert in this area but [these guys](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=60979) are.